# Optimize django query

Tags: mysql, django, optimization

Implemented a new feature on the site as if it were a "social network".

The various actions users make, receive messages and stuff. Their friends can see all the action.

```
class userMuralEntry(models.Model):
   user_src = models.ForeignKey(userInfo, related_name="user_src")
   user = models.ManyToManyField(userInfo, related_name="user_dest")
   user_follow = models.ManyToManyField(userInfo, related_name="user_follow")
   private = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   content = models.TextField()
   date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
   last_update = models.DateTimeField()

   object_type = models.ForeignKey(muralType)

   content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
   object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Every time i access my frontpage, i get ALL my friends actions, except the private ones.
So, i made this django model queries

```
  mural_list = db.userMuralEntry.objects.filter(Q(user__pk__in=friend_list)|Q(user_src__pk__in=friend_list)).order_by('-last_update')
  m = mural_list.exclude(
  Q(private=True),
  ~Q(user_src=me_db) & ~Q(user=me_db))

  m = m.distinct()
```

all this code generate this BIG query (here with the explain output)

```
SELECT DISTINCT myps3t_usermuralentry.id, 
                myps3t_usermuralentry.user_src_id, 
                myps3t_usermuralentry.private, 
                myps3t_usermuralentry.content, 
                myps3t_usermuralentry.DATE, 
                myps3t_usermuralentry.last_update, 
                myps3t_usermuralentry.object_type_id, 
                myps3t_usermuralentry.content_type_id, 
                myps3t_usermuralentry.object_id 
FROM   myps3t_usermuralentry 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN myps3t_usermuralentry_user 
         ON ( myps3t_usermuralentry.id = 
              myps3t_usermuralentry_user.usermuralentry_id ) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN myps3t_userinfo t4 
         ON ( myps3t_usermuralentry.user_src_id = t4.id ) 
WHERE  ( ( myps3t_usermuralentry_user.userinfo_id = 20877 
            OR myps3t_usermuralentry.user_src_id = 20877 ) 
         AND NOT ( myps3t_usermuralentry.private = 1 
                   AND ( NOT (( t4.id = 21095 
                                AND NOT ( t4.id IS NULL ) )) 
                         AND NOT ( myps3t_usermuralentry.id IN 
                                   (SELECT u1.usermuralentry_id 
                                    FROM 
                                   myps3t_usermuralentry_user u1 
                                                                WHERE  ( 
                                   u1.userinfo_id = 
                                   21095 
                                   AND 
                                   u1.usermuralentry_id 
                                   IS 
                                   NOT 
                                   NULL 
                                                                       )) ) ) ) 
       ) 
ORDER  BY myps3t_usermuralentry.last_update; 



mysql> explain SELECT DISTINCT `myps3t_usermuralentry`.`id`, `myps3t_usermuralentry`.`user_src_id`, `myps3t_usermuralentry`.`private`, `myps3t_usermuralentry`.`content`, `myps3t_usermuralentry`.`date`, `myps3t_usermuralentry`.`last_update`, `myps3t_usermuralentry`.`object_type_id`, `myps3t_usermuralentry`.`content_type_id`, `myps3t_usermuralentry`.`object_id` FROM `myps3t_usermuralentry` LEFT OUTER JOIN `myps3t_usermuralentry_user` ON (`myps3t_usermuralentry`.`id` = `myps3t_usermuralentry_user`.`usermuralentry_id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `myps3t_userinfo` T4 ON (`myps3t_usermuralentry`.`user_src_id` = T4.`id`) WHERE ((`myps3t_usermuralentry_user`.`userinfo_id` = 20877  OR `myps3t_usermuralentry`.`user_src_id` = 20877 ) AND NOT (`myps3t_usermuralentry`.`private` = 1  AND (NOT ((T4.`id` = 21095  AND NOT (T4.`id` IS NULL))) AND NOT (`myps3t_usermuralentry`.`id` IN (SELECT U1.`usermuralentry_id` FROM `myps3t_usermuralentry_user` U1 WHERE (U1.`userinfo_id` = 21095  AND U1.`usermuralentry_id` IS NOT NULL)))))) ORDER BY `myps3t_usermuralentry`.`last_update` DESC LIMIT 20;
+----+--------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table                      | type            | possible_keys                                                                             | key               | key_len | ref                                               | rows   | Extra                              |
+----+--------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | myps3t_usermuralentry      | ALL             | myps3t_usermuralentry_99bd10ae                                                            | NULL              | NULL    | NULL                                              | 665410 | Using temporary; Using filesort    |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | myps3t_usermuralentry_user | ref             | usermuralentry_id,myps3t_usermuralentry_user_bcd7114e                                     | usermuralentry_id | 4       | fabriciols_ps3t.myps3t_usermuralentry.id          |      2 | Using where; Using index; Distinct |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | T4                         | eq_ref          | PRIMARY                                                                                   | PRIMARY           | 4       | fabriciols_ps3t.myps3t_usermuralentry.user_src_id |      1 | Using where; Using index; Distinct |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | U1                         | unique_subquery | usermuralentry_id,myps3t_usermuralentry_user_bcd7114e,myps3t_usermuralentry_user_6b192ca7 | usermuralentry_id | 8       | func,const                                        |      1 | Using index; Using where           |
+----+--------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show indexes from myps3t_usermuralentry ;
+-----------------------+------------+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table                 | Non_unique | Key_name                       | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-----------------------+------------+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| myps3t_usermuralentry |          0 | PRIMARY                        |            1 | id              | A         |      665410 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| myps3t_usermuralentry |          1 | myps3t_usermuralentry_99bd10ae |            1 | user_src_id     | A         |       22180 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| myps3t_usermuralentry |          1 | myps3t_usermuralentry_ae71a55b |            1 | object_type_id  | A         |           8 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| myps3t_usermuralentry |          1 | myps3t_usermuralentry_e4470c6e |            1 | content_type_id | A         |          13 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-----------------------+------------+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

i made some tweak on index, but its too much slow... a user with 3-4 friends is taking like 5 secondos !

this table have, for now, 500 thousands rows.

Some idea of improvements ? Is my django code messy ? Is best to make the query in my own hands ?

Comment: Why all of the Q objects, instead of chaining filter/exclude calls?

Comment: beacause i need a OR operation...(user OR user_src) is there a way to do without Q objects ?

Comment: Your exclude could probably be simplified.

Comment: well, i need to exclude all the private entries that I'M not involved, and i can be source (user_src) or destination (user) of the message... how can i do this ? how can i use normal filter to make a NOT EQUAL ?

Comment: Once again, you can chain exclude and filter calls.

Comment: sorry, i don't get it... can you show a example ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8354/discussion-between-fabriciols-and-marcin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read this again: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/

There are a number of ways that you can simplify your code. For example:

```
mural_list = db.userMuralEntry.objects.filter(Q(user__pk__in=friend_list)|Q(user_src__pk__in=friend_list))
```

is equivalent to:

```
mural_list = db.userMuralEntry.objects.filter(user__pk__in=friend_list)|db.userMuralEntry.objects.filter(user_src__pk__in=friend_list)
```

and

```
m = mural_list.exclude(
  Q(private=True),
  ~Q(user_src=me_db) & ~Q(user=me_db))
```

is equivalent to

```
m = mural_list.exclude(private=True).exclude(user_src=me_db).exclude(user=me_db)
```

Note that it is probably better to place order_by clauses at the end, to avoid outer joins on ordered_by queries.

The final optimised sql was kindly shared by @fabriciols here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2795524#2795524